# Kotlin function that receives two numbers and returns sum and multiply of them

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

I am newbie in Kotlin lambda expressions, I try to build a function to have two arguments and returns a function with to parameters:

```
val sumAndMultiply:(Int,Int) -> (Int,Int) -> Unit = { a,b -> (a+b,a*b)}
```

But it's not compiling.
Generally how can I return a headless function in Kotlin?

Comment: Even disregarding syntactic errors, i don't see what arguments you'd pass to the function that returns a function. I see a nullary function that returns a binary function.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ok, so please help me creating a function that has two arguments and returns a function with two arguments.

Comment: BTW what's a "headless function"? Did you mean a `val` holding a lambda instead of a regular function declaration?

Answer (score 4):

> please help me creating a function that has two arguments and returns a function with two arguments.

This is a function that takes two arguments and returns a function with two arguments.

```
fun binaryFunReturningBinaryFun(a: Int, b: Int): (Int, Int) -> Int =
        { x, y -> (a + x) * (b + y) }
```

Comment: Correct in what way? Syntactically?

Comment: Please add a sample of how to use binaryFunReturningBinaryFun and print the sum and multiply in this sample. thanks

Comment: I asked you several times to explain what you really want, but all I got is "help me write a function taking two arguments, that returns a function taking two arguments". This is what I provided. I still have no idea what you want your function-returning function to actually do. Specifically, as I already stated, I don't see what role each of the four arguments should play (two to the outer function, two to the function it returns).

Comment: :| actually I want to replace Listener interfaces with lambda functions

Comment: I have no way to help you further based on your input so far.

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin has no support for [tuples](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/migrating-tuples/). You would have to use Pair:

```
val sumAndMultiply: ((Int,Int) -> Pair<Int,Int>) = { a,b -> Pair(a+b,a*b) }
```

Another solution would be to create data class, for example:

```
data class SumAndMultiplication(val sum: Int, val multiplication: Int)
val sumAndMultiply2: ((Int,Int) -> SumAndMultiplication) = { a,b -> SumAndMultiplication(a+b,a*b) }
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done same thing using below code and it worked.

```
var rtn:(Int,Int) -> Unit = {x,y -> println("${x} ${y}")}
val sumAndMultiply: (Int,Int) -> Any = { a,b -> rtn(a+b,a*b)}
sumAndMultiply(1,3)
```

**Explanation**

You want to return a function from your lambda function so, first of all you have to create the function which you want to return. So, i have created `rtn` function for this. I have created `rtn` also as a lambda function. You can create as you want.

Then i have changed return type of `sumAndMultiply` lambda function and returned function `rtn` which we have created.